# Incorrect icons showing in android using react-native-elements

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-elements

I am using `react-native-elements` to show icons in my app.

But icons show incorrect in Android.

**Android**:
[image: Android]

**IOS**:

[image: Ios]

```
import { Icon } from 'react-native-elements';
<Icon
     style={styles.btnIcon}
     name="user"
     type="feather"
     iconStyle={styles.btnIconStyle}
     size={16}/>
```

**package.json**

```
"react-native-vector-icons": "^7.1.0",
"react-native-elements": "^2.3.2",
"react-native": "^0.63.2",
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are running this application on both platform and problem occurs only in android, then I think you should try cleaning npm cache and rebuild your application.

Kill the node.

Run the command in your terminal - `npm cache clean --force`

Re-run your application.